# duplication issue with dynamic form in tabs view <ion-slide> while coming from another tabs in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am creating a dynamic form in my **controller.js** like

var createForm="";

createForm +="";

for(var i=0; i<2; i++){

if(field_type=="text"){

```
createForm += "<input type='text' ng-model=user,"+some_value+">"
```

}else if(field_type=="password"){

```
createForm += "<input type='password' ng-model=user,"+some_value+">"
```

}

}
  createForm +="";

var temp = $compile(createForm)($scope);
  angular.element(document.getElementById('dynamic_form')).append(temp);

Note :- Here i have tried to use **angular.element(document.getElementById('dynamic_form')).html(temp);**

but it is not working, div is not getting appear on the view.

**my view is :**

```
<ion-slide>

        <div class="list list-inset" >

                <div id="dynamic_form"></div>

        </div>

</ion-slide>
```

Comment: Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, Actually here ng-model=user."+some_value+" and out of the for() loop createForm +="<div>" and createForm +="</div>"    here some_value is nothing but the values getting from SQLite db.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code and approach:

- You have undeclared variables which will throw JavaScript exceptions.
- Looks like you're trying to have a dynamic value for ng-model.
- It's not best practice to do DOM manipulations in controller.

I think what you are trying to do can be achieved easily the "angular" way (using the dom as the template).
Here's a [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AJy1oShCxY8quJPlrlmU) too.

**HTML**

```
<ion-slide>
  <div class="list list-inset" >
    <form>
      <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
        <label ng-bind="field.label"></label> 
        <input type="{{field.type}}" ng-model="field.value">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</ion-slide>
```

**Controller Code**

```
$scope.fields = [
  {type: 'text', label: 'User Name', value: ''},
  {type: 'password', label: 'Password', value: ''}
];
```

Comment: what do you mean "one by one"? Can you provide what your data structure looks like? How are you populating (for example) the value of "field_type" in your question code?

Comment: Hi o4ohel thanks for the reply, Here i am getting all the value from my SQLite database one by one, If the value is in json format that it is easy to use ng-repeat, but what in the case of database value. kindly help me

Comment: I am using select query to get the column_type and column_value like:-  tx.executeSql("select * from form_template_column ",[],function(tx, result){}); and now inside select query i am reading column_type and column_label, with these db table item values i am creating a form in controller.js and then inside my view in a div **dynamic_form** appending the created div, as created above in the question. here form_template_column is my table name

Answer (score 0):

Thanks o4ohel for all your support,
Finally i got a way to solve the issue.

Here first i added jQuery plugin to get support for

angular.element(document.body).html() function
and then i did as mention below :-

**var temp = $compile(createForm)($scope); 
angular.element(`document.getElementById('dynamic_form')`).html("");
angular.element(`document.getElementById('dynamic_form')`).append(temp);**

this above lines solve my issue.

Kindly correct me if my way is wrong.

Thanks